# When I am trying to extrude it's creating a loop cut like thing around it, how to get rid of it?

Tags: modeling, extrude

[image: I am trying to extrude this part]I am new to blender and I am trying to extrude `(pressed the hotkey "E")` an object it is creating a cut in the middle of the object. Here are some screenshots[image]

Can any one please tell how to get rid of that cut.

Comment: hello, where are you trying to extrude exactly?

Comment: @moonboots posted a picture that where am I trying to extrude please check

Comment: if you select the top and extrude upwards, it will leave an edge loop, its seems normal to me, it's an extrusion, if you don't want to leave an edge loop, just move the selection up. Now, if you want to get rid of this edge loop, select it and dissolve with Ctrl X

Comment: I believe you can just move top part by pressing G

Comment: @Crantisz Thank you so much, it worked for me !!!